# Trying to create a function that tests correlation for a list of dataframe columns against the same list

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop

I am trying to create a function that will iterate through a list (a list of columns in my dataframe) and test for correlation.

Then create a for list to run through the same list of columns and run the function for each column.

This is the code I have:

```
col_list = fifa_dataset[['Agility','Acceleration','Balance','Positioning','Skill Moves','BallControl','Crossing','Finishing','Reactions','SprintSpeed']]
def collinear(x):
  for a in col_list:
    return x.corr[a]
for i in col_list:
  print(collinear(fifa_dataset[i]))
```

This is my traceback message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-a4dd1a4478dd> in <module>()
      4     return x.corr[a]
      5 for i in col_list:
----> 6   print(collinear(fifa_dataset[i]))

<ipython-input-56-a4dd1a4478dd> in collinear(x)
      2 def collinear(x):
      3   for a in col_list:
----> 4     return x.corr[a]
      5 for i in col_list:
      6   print(collinear(fifa_dataset[i]))

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: you wanted `()` for a function call, not `[]` which is for indexing or accessing an object by key

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you got the wrong pair of parentheses [] instead of ():
This should do it:

```
def collinear(x):
  for a in col_list:
    return x.corr(a)
```

Comment: still returns an error message, this time TypeError: unsupported type: <class 'str'>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
def collinear(x):
  for a in col_list:
    return x.corr(x[a])
```